# Expr and count in shell

Tags: shell

I learn a shell code from a video,and there is a code:

```
#!/bin/sh

i=1

while true
do
    echo $i
    i='expr $i + 1'
done
```

The code above gives me output is:

```
1
expr $i + 1
expr $i + 1
expr $i + 1
......
```

But in the video the output are consistent numbers,why the same code shows different results?

Comment: To evaluate a _command_ on the RHS of a variable assignment you must enclose it in _backticks_ (`\`...\` `), or, preferably, `$(...)`. Enclosing something in _single_ quotes causes the string's content to be taken _literally_.

Comment: `$(...)` won't necessarily work in this case, because the OP seems to use `sh`.  Only on systems where sh is linked to, say, `bash`, it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As aready mentioned in a comment, you have the wrong quotes; the video will have had backticks (`` ` ``, [ASCII 96](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/60/index.htm)), not single quotes (`'`, [ASCII 39](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27/index.htm)).

Additionally, anything which uses this obsolescent syntax for command substitution or `expr` is at least 20 years behind, and should be avoided in favor of modern POSIX constructs.

```
#!/bin/sh

i=1

while true
do
    echo "$i"  # Note proper quoting
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

In Bash, you could use brace expansion or a C-style `for` loop, but these are not portable to modern `sh`.

If you need your code to be portable to pre-POSIX systems, my recommendation would still be to learn the modern constructs first, especially for simple code like this (where in a production system you would probably want to use Awk or Perl for a loop like this anyway).